# How to return a boolean from findOne function MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, sequelize.js

I want to use the result of `findOne` as a condition of an `if` statement. I can't return `true` or `false`, I saw that for the `async` function it's different but despite several attempts nothing worked.

**Controller.js**

```
  // Find a single User with a sub
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
const sub = req.params.sub;

User.findOne({sub})
  .then(data => {
res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
res.status(500).send({
message: "Error retrieving User with sub=" +sub
});
  });
};
```

**Front-end:**

```
//INFO SAVE AND UPDATE CONDITION

async function exist() {
let x = await InfoDataService.get(data.sub)
console.log(x);
if (x === null) {

return true;

}
return false;
}

if ( exist() ) {
    InfoDataService.create(data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('create', response.data);
        setInfo({
          id: response.data.id,
          sub: response.data.sub,
          email: response.data.email,
          firstname: response.data.firstname,
          lastname: response.data.lastname
        });
      })
      
  } else {
    InfoDataService.update(sub, data)
      .then((response) => {
                
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to do that. Both are just complementary to each other.

```js
// option 1 
if (x) {
    return true;
}
return false;

// OR
// option 2
if (!x) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```